# How do I plot a histogram using row numbers as bins?

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram of genome-wide interaction data for a set of genes. The Dataframe appears correct when I print it or save to csv, but when I attempt to create the histogram, the binning is wrong and the values appear incorrect. There's a lot to clean up to make it more efficient as I'm just trying to get it working right now, but I'm sure you can see my inexperience in the code as it's not the most elegant thing in the world.

```
def plot_data():
    args = parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    genes = csv.reader(open(args.genes, 'r'), delimiter='\t')
    out = csv.reader(open(args.output, 'r'), delimiter='\t')
    arr1 = []
    arr2 = []
    for x in out: # create two separate lists to drop duplicates and create a single ordered coordinate column in Dataframe
        arr1.append(str(x[0]) + "\t" + str(x[2]) + "\t" + str(x[3]))
        arr2.append(str(x[1]) + "\t" + str(x[2]) + "\t" + str(x[3]))
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.split('\t') for x in arr1], columns=['c1', 'contacts', 'gene']).drop_duplicates(('gene', 'c1'), keep=False)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([x.split('\t') for x in arr2], columns=['c2', 'contacts', 'gene']).drop_duplicates(('gene', 'c2'), keep=False)
    dfm = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['contacts','gene'], right_on = ['contacts','gene'], how='outer').fillna(0)
    dfm[['c1', 'c2']] = dfm[['c1', 'c2']].apply(pd.to_numeric) # change 'c1' and 'c2' values to int64 numeric values
    dfm['c'] = dfm['c1'] + dfm['c2'] # create index by summing 'c1' and 'c2' indices
    dfm = dfm[['c', 'contacts', 'gene']] # drop 'c1' and 'c2' columns and keep the merged 'c' column
    dfm = dfm.pivot(index='c', columns='gene', values='contacts').fillna(0).reindex(dfm.index, fill_value=0).apply(pd.to_numeric) # re-arranges dataframe so that 'gene' is the column name and 'c' is the row index
    dfm = dfm[dfm.index <= 2337] # remove rows with 'c' greater than 2337
    dfm = dfm[dfm.index > 0] # remove 0 row from 'c'
    num_bins = len(dfm.index)
    dfm.hist(bins=num_bins, sharex=True, sharey=True)
    plt.xlabel("Bin number", fontsize=12)
    plt.ylabel("Interaction count", fontsize=12)
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.show()
plot = plot_data()
```

This is just a snippet, but the Dataframe output from this code looks something like this (the actual Dataframe has 2337 rows plus the header row):

```
    gene1       gene2       gene3
1   2498.44     741.13      78.07
2   0.0         799.87      113.44
3   1463.36     1715.41     83.52
4   799.83      0.0         140.63
5   476.46      1138.58     105.91
6   353.92      667.51      125.78
7   349.17      335.82      114.90
8   0.0         0.0         0.0
9   179.30      287.71      126.03
10  139.17      207.05      67.16
11  95.32       94.28       69.63
12  64.50       66.24       25.24
13  38.83       67.29       28.50
14  27.85       48.96       29.81
15  37.86       51.28       17.29
16  18.80       42.25       16.09
17  39.28       29.57       21.91
18  22.02       37.41       13.73
19  17.02       38.08       10.41
20  27.27       20.55       14.17
```

For some reason when I run this I get an output that doesn't show the 0 values (from the Dataframe) in the correct locations and the other values appear to be incorrect. The binning is odd considering there should be 2337 bins, but the x-axis goes way past 2500. Here is an example of one such histogram (sorry, just created the account):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo0qC.png

I'm probably missing some obvious mistake in the code, but I've been stuck on this since yesterday.

Comment: There is a difference between number of bins and range of the bins. There probably are 2337 bins, as you specify in your function, but the range of the bins are what defines the x-axis, not the number of bins.

Comment: Is there a way to specify each row as a bin?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to visualize. Take `dfm.loc[1,:]` (`dfm.loc[1,['gene1','gene2','gene3']]`?)- you say you want that to be a bin, how should the data in that row be displayed?

Comment: I want each gene to have a separate histogram with the x-axis being the genome coordinate (i.e. the first column) and the y-axis to be the contact counts (i.e. each value in the row). For for this data I would have three histograms with 2337 bins, one for each genome coordinate.